Celebrating 10th year anniversary
It has been ten years of Reverse Engineering on the StackExchange network, can you believe it?
From modest beginnings as a proposal on Area51 by X01xtTv to the long journey as a beta site and finally our site graduation at the end of 2021 I am sure many of you will have fond memories of particular questions or answers that stood out to you or of the sense of community our Q&A site can give.
The site started out as the place where reverse engineering questions could be asked that didn't fit on the r/ReverseEngineering subreddit (meanwhile they have the associated r/AskReverseEngineering, too). Our long serving moderator Igor as well as Rolf Rolles -- both also moderators on the aforementioned subreddit -- played a big role in advertising our site within the reverse engineering community at large.
Site activity, albeit no comparison to the likes of StackOverflow, shows a steady flow of questions and answers and a core group of active members, on and off.
Of some we know that they reverse engineer in their professional capacity, but there are plenty of hobbyists frequenting our site as well. If you have a brief look on our user list you will notice some names that are well known within the reverse engineering community due to them sharing their experience and skills through tools, papers or books. This makes for a healthy mix of experts and those aspiring to become experts.
What is perhaps among the most intriguing traits of our site is that while there is a bias towards software reverse engineering, we will happily accept questions about reverse engineering hardware, be it electronic devices or mechanical ones ...
And now it is time to celebrate our anniversary. If you feel like it, leave a comment or share something that you associate with our site in the form of an answer.

Official blog post

keeps me busy , makes me learn , urges me to share , happy Tin Jubilee

Congratulations to you all. I hope to see more stories here. I really enjoyed chatting with your current moderators. Happy 10!
